# multivariate nonlinear regression

Tags: c++, machine-learning, regression

i am new to machine learning and i wanted to implement multivariate nonlinear regression , and i cant seem to find any good C++ library on it 
(for example: data)

```
    y        x1         x2       x3          x4       x5         x6      
4.52e+005  8.32e+000 4.10e+001 8.801e+002 1.29e+002 3.22e+002 1.26e+002 
3.585e+005 8.30e+000 2.10e+001 7.099e+003 1.10e+003 2.40e+003 1.13e+003 
3.521e+005 7.25e+000 5.20e+001 1.467e+003 1.91e+002 4.96e+002 1.77e+002 
3.413e+005 5.64e+000 5.20e+001 1.274e+003 2.35e+002 5.58e+002 2.19e+002 
3.422e+005 3.84e+000 5.20e+001 1.627e+003 2.81e+002 5.65e+002 2.59e+002
```

i need non linear regression model to predict the output for given input variables(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6)

Comment: What have you googled?

Comment: Have you looked at TMVA (http://tmva.sourceforge.net/) which comes as part of ROOT (http://root.cern.ch)?

Comment: You have five data points and six variables. The system is under specified. How go you know you need a non-linear model?

Comment: it is just an example.. it has more than 20000 data points

Answer (score 2):

I would try out kernel ridge regression and/or support vector regression on this.  Either of them will probably work quite well.

The [dlib C++ library](http://dlib.net) has easy to use implementations of both of these methods.  See the [support vector regression](http://dlib.net/svr_ex.cpp.html) or [kernel ridge regression](http://dlib.net/krr_regression_ex.cpp.html) example programs for the details.  Note that these examples show just one input variable but all you need to do is change the dimensionality of the input vector to something other than 1.  So in the examples, that means you just change the line

```
typedef matrix<double,1,1> sample_type;
```

to

```
typedef matrix<double,6,1> sample_type;
```

and then they will work on 6 input variables.

Comment: The examples don't mention this but you should also make sure your 6 inputs are normalized so they are all relatively in the same range.  For example, if you have an input that varies between 0 and 1e5 while the others are between 0 and 1 then what will happen is that all the smaller variables will be basically ignored.  Usually subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation (so that each variable has mean 0 and variance 1) is a good way to do this.